# Implementing Overflow Checking in 4-bit Adder/Subtractor (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am rather new (3 weeks) to VHDL, and I am having a problem in my latest assignment, which involves implementing overflow checking in a simple 4-bit adder:

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity add_sub_4bit is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           b : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
              sel: in STD_LOGIC );
           --sum : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) 
end add_sub_4bit;

architecture Behavioral of add_sub_4bit is
signal localflow : STD_LOGIC;
signal localsum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

begin
    localsum <= a + b when sel = '1'
    else
    a - b;
process(a,b,localsum) begin
    if a(3) = '0' AND b(3) = '0' AND localsum(3) = '1' then
        localflow <= '1'; 
    elsif  a(3) = '1' AND b(3) = '1' AND localsum(3) = '0' then
        localflow <='1';
    else
        localflow <='0';
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Now, the test cases are as such:
A=5, B=-3, giving 0 to sel adds them, 1 subtracts.
A=6, B=2, working much the same.

Now, given that the numbers are signed, of course, they are two's complement numbers, so is the result. However, I can only detect overflow in a case of adding 6 (0110) and 2 (0010), giving out -8 (1000), which is obviously an overflow case in 4-bit. But, when doing 5 -(-3), the result is much the same, 1000, but since I have given numbers of two different signs, I cannot detect overflow using my method.

My teacher has suggested that we change the sign of B depending on the value of sel - I tried something like making b <= b+"1000" based on that but that didn't help, and I don't know of other ways, being very new to the language. What can I do to get a proper program? Thank you.

Comment: In HW subtraction adds the two's complement of b (not b + 1), the + 1 uses carry in. When subtracting you should be using the sign of the actual b adder operand for overflow which would be `opb_sign <= b(3) when sel = '1' else not b(3);`. You could show this as a separate multiplexer (selector) or using XOR collapse this to the term `(b(3) xor not sel)`. Also collapsing the original overflow selector gives `localflow <= a(3) xor b(3) xor not sel xor localsum(3);` Parentheses are unneeded, XOR is commutative. and not is the higher priority.

Comment: Hi there,
Your suggestion worked - I kept the same program, with an additonal mux. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

Don't do that. Especially if you want the numbers to be signed. Normal to use is:

```
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
```

After that, you should cast the `std_logic_vector` to the wanted data type, e.g. 'signed', for the correct arithmetic.

Secondly, don't use `inout`. VHDL is not so good with bidirectional assignments. Either use `in` or `out`.

So combining the above, you could do (n.b. not the best code):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity add_sub_4bit is
    Port (
        a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        sel: in STD_LOGIC;
        sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        overflow : out std_logic
        );
end add_sub_4bit;

architecture Behavioral of add_sub_4bit is
signal localflow : STD_LOGIC;
signal locala, localb, localsum : signed(4 downto 0); -- one bit more then input
signal sumout : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

begin
    locala <= resize(signed(a), 5);
    localb <= resize(signed(b), 5);
    localsum <= locala + localb when sel = '1' else locala - localb;
    -- overflow occurs when bit 3 is not equal to the sign bit(4)
    localflow <= '1' when localsum(3) /= localsum(4) else '0';
    -- convert outputs
    sumout <= std_logic_vector(localsum);
    --outputs
    sum <= sumout(4)&sumout(2 downto 0);
    overflow <= localflow;
end Behavioral;
```

You can test this using a testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity add_sub_4bit_tb is
end add_sub_4bit_tb;

architecture Behavioral of add_sub_4bit_tb is
signal sel : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
signal a, b, sum : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin
    uut: entity work.add_sub_4bit
    port map (a, b, sel(0), sum);

    test: process
    begin
        for sel_o in 0 to 1 loop
            sel <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(sel_o, 1));
            for a_o in -8 to 7 loop
                a <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(a_o, 4));
                for b_o in -8 to 7 loop
                    b <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(b_o, 4));
                    wait for 1 ns;
                end loop;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```